# How to cast a object to an anonymous type in a different assembly?

Tags: c#, dynamic, .net-4.0, datasource, anonymous-types

I have a `GridView` where my `DataSource` is:

```
items.Select(i => new { ID = i.ID, Foo = i }).ToList();
```

In the `RowDataBound` I want to access the object, but I don't know how to cast it...

```
grid.RowDataBound += (s, e) =>
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        dynamic item = e.Row.DataItem as 'what?';
    }
};
```

How can I access this object properties?

---

### Steps to reproduce

1. Create a website
2. Create a page (default.aspx) and place a `<asp:GridView ID="grid" runat="server" />`
3. In the code behind:

add

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs ev)
{
    var provider = new FooProvider();

    grid.DataSource = provider.Elements;
    grid.RowDataBound += (s, e) =>
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            dynamic item = e.Row.DataItem;

            var test = item.ID;
        }
    };
    grid.DataBind();
}
```

1. Create a Class Library project
2. Add a file `FooProvider.cs`

Code:

```
public class FooProvider
{
    public IEnumerable<dynamic> Elements
    {
        get
        {
            return new int[] { 1, 2, 3 }
                .Select(i => new { ID = i, Foo = i * 3 }).ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

Then add the reference on the website.

---

Expected result: Get the ID of the anonymous object.

Current result:

> RuntimeBinderException was unhandled by user code
>
> 'object' does not contain a definition for 'ID'

---

Is reflection the only way?

Comment: What do you mean by casting to an anonymous type?

Comment: If you don't know the type of the object in advance, how do you expect to access its properties anyway? Reflection? If you don't know the type of the items in your GridView then what would you do with them?

Comment: @jamietre: He knows what type it is: he just hasn't declared a class for it. It's an anonymous class with a specific signature.

Comment: Ah ok - actually interesting, would "var" allow the properties of an anonymous type to be used? I don't think so because there's a missing link between DataItem and var. Class it is.

Comment: @jamietre: Exactly. `var` would work once you've actually cast the object to the right type, but now that I realize these are in two different assemblies, there's no way to perform that cast.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using `dynamic` you don't need to cast it at all. Just cast the values that you know the type of.

```
dynamic item = e.Row.DataItem;
DoSomething((int)item.Foo)
```

(Though I agree with David B that I'd rather have a type safe, declared class.)

And by the way, there is a trick you can use with generics which would allow you to do something like this:

```
var item = e.Row.DataItem.CastAnonymous(new {ID = 1, Foo = 1});
DoSomething(item.Foo);
```

... but I think that's the worst of the three options.

**Edit**

When working across assemblies, reflection is the only way to do what you're asking. Anonymous types were always intended to stay within the confines of a single method--that's why you can't declare them as a parameter or a return type. They make things like LINQ statements far less tedious, but their purpose is not to make C# into a scripting language. Is there a reason that you're dead-set against declaring a strong type?

**Edit 2**

Several years on now, we've got some lightweight type options available without using anonymous types.

Records allow you to do a class declaration with a single line of code:

```
public record FooElement(int ID, int Foo);
```

```
public IEnumerable<FooElement> Elements
{
    get
    {
        return new int[] { 1, 2, 3 }
            .Select(i => new FooElement(i, i * 3)).ToList();
    }
}
```

```
var item = (FooElement) e.Row.DataItem;
var test = item.ID;
```

And if you *really* don't want to create a named class to represent your return type, you can use ValueTuple syntax:

```
public IEnumerable<(int ID, int Foo)> Elements
{
    get
    {
        return new int[] { 1, 2, 3 }
            .Select(i => (i, i * 3)).ToList();
    }
}
```

```
var item = ((int ID, int Foo)) e.Row.DataItem;
var test = item.ID;
```

or

```
var (test, _) = ((int, int)) e.Row.DataItem;
```

Comment: DataItem is an object, `item` ends up being of type `object`. When I access `.Foo` it says `object` doesn't have a property `Foo`

Comment: @BrunoLM: `item` is actually a `dynamic` with an underlying `object` of your anonymous type. Due the the `dynamic` nature of it, you can say `item.Foo`. I just tried it: it works.

Comment: I noticed that my problem happens because I have different assemblies. (added more info on the question)

Comment: @BrunoLM: I guess that's not too surprising: even anonymous types with the same signature are incompatible if they're in different assemblies. I'd say this is all the more reason you should define a class. When `dynamic` was announced, purists foresaw that people would try to use it like this, and trembled. It has its uses, but this is not one of them.

Comment: I guess what I am trying to do is "select whatever from database and return it in a single object". Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 7):

Don't use anonymous types.  Make a class.

```
public class MyCustomRow
{
  int ID {get;set;}
  Foo Foo {get;set;}
}
```

(wtf? dynamic?)

Comment: To make the point more general, anonymous types are a convience that can be used when a type is only used in a single place in your code and never needs to be referenced by name.  You're doing something that references your type by name, and so therefor you can't use an anonymous type.

Comment: Well sure, Nimrand - I decided not to describe why one should not try to use the name of an anonymous type in my answer to avoid redundancy.

Answer (score 0):

var item = e.Row.DataItem; doesn't work?

can you not create a custom model class to store the information so that you can cast it?

Comment: DataItem is an object `public virtual object DataItem { get; set; }` It doesn't have the property `Foo`

Comment: no, `DataItem` is an object. It must be cast to the appropriate type in order to be used (well, normally).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can. I had something similar going on a while back and as I recall i had to use <% %> notation to refer to the anonymous properties (ID and Foo, in your case). If you have more complex processing to do in your RowDataBound you'll have to define a class.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the opensource [Impromptu-Interface](http://code.google.com/p/impromptu-interface/) framework to duck cast an anonymous type to a static interface allowing it to work in another assembly.

Impromptu interface is actually using the the same api as the dynamic keyword except that it sets the context to the framework you declared your anonymous type in. That way the dynamic invocation will resolve properly (since anonymous types are compiled as `internal`).

```
return new int[] { 1, 2, 3 }
            .Select(i => new { ID = i, Foo = i * 3 }
                            .ActLike<IMyMadeUpInterface>()).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use DataBinder.Eval() ?

```
    grid.RowDataBound += (s, e) =>
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            var test = DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Id");
        }
    }
```